# Stash category ID and entries

Tags: stash, categories

I have tried to use Cat2 addon to retrieve category ID based on a category group. Later I want to use stashed category ID to retrieve entries form a channel based on a selected category. Code looks like:

```
{exp:stash:set name="catid" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3"}
{exp:cat2:id category_url_title="{segment_2}" category_group="5" parse="inward"}
{category_id}
{/exp:cat2:id}
{/exp:stash:set}

CatID#: {exp:stash:get name='catid'}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="collection" category="{exp:stash:get name='catid'}" url_title="{segment_3}" status="open"}
        {title}
        {collection_description}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

It displays proper CatID# but I'm not getting any entries. When I "hardcode" that CatID# instead of `{exp:stash:get name='catid'}` I'm able to retrieve related entries.

Any clue what is going on there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution [here](http://pilotmade.com/blog/simple-expressionengine-stash-parse-order)

> If you need to use a Stash variable that was created within a Channel
>   Entries loop earlier in a template as a parameter in a Channel Entries
>   loop, you can delay the parse order of the second Channel Entries loop
>   such that the variable gets set prior to the loop being executed. For
>   example if you got a list of entry IDs of related entries (from
>   Relationships or Playa) you could put those in the entry_id parameter
>   and then print out the entries in the correct order. This could be
>   used for categories, statuses, search values, whatever.

Example code:

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="XXX" fixed_order="{stash:places}" entry_id="{stash:places}" dynamic="no"}
    {title}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```